# Install jQuery using Git

Tags: jquery, git, jquery-ui, version-control

I am using jQuery 1.X and jQueryUI.  Previously, I have just downloaded the latest stable version, uploaded it to my server, and away we go.

I've recently gotten into Git, and wonder how I got so for without it.  For 3rd party libraries such us these, I find submodules work well.

Reading the download page http://jquery.com/download/, it talks about bleeding edge versions which I definitely do not want.  Instead, I just want the latest stable version (jQuery 1.11.1).  The page does describe using Git to install, but I can't figure out which version it will install.  It does describe doing:

```
git clone git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
git checkout 1.2.6 # or I could likely change to 1.11.1
```

Would this install every version of jQuery, or just 1.2.6?  I tried doing it and `git checkout 1.2.6` didn't work until I entered the jquery directory resulting from cloning it.  Was this to be expected (the documentation did not tell me to do so).  Will using Git to download jQuery this way work with submodules?  Are there benefits to install this way, or should I just stick with my  trued and proven version of manually downloading a zip?

EDIT.  After checking out 1.11.1, I see the jQuery file in the dist/ directory.  1.2.6 puts it in the root directory.

Based on the above, will this same approach work with jQueryUI?

Thank you

Comment: This question is about how to use the git software in general, and is not specific to jQuery.

Comment: @Blazemonger.  I agree.  I put Git as the first tag, but it didn't show up as first.  Think I should remove the jquery and jquery-ui tags?

Comment: @Blazemonger I would say this question is also about JavaScript library package management, not just git. Here git is used as a package manager, but the OP wants to compare this to alternative package management technologies.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout 1.2.6` will create a folder structure with just version 1.2.6 of jQuery, not all versions.

It was to be expected that the `git` command did not work until the jquery directory was the current directory. Git commands expect to be executed in a folder structure that has a git repository folder, named `.git`, which contains all version information.

You could use the jquery.git folder as a submodule, since it is a repository. However, submodules are a fairly advanced use of Git. I would not recommend them to a beginner.

An advantage of downloading using git is that you can get new versions of jQuery by doing `git pull` and switch between different versions using `git checkout`. Pretty neat I think.

An alternative technology that is focused on package handling javascript libraries is [bower](http://bower.io/), you might want to look into that. Bower works on top of git, but has functionality for analyzing and handling dependencies between libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bower](http://bower.io/), the most popular package manager for frontend libraries.

It uses git under the hood, but id doesn't clones a lot of unnecessary stuff which git repositories contain.

Both `jquery` and `jquery.ui` are available as bower packages. You can also use any versions you want and successfully lock them for the project.

You can search required packages [here](http://bower.io/search/).